# How can I convert base of decimal string to another base?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

here is my codes;

```
{Sayitabani=orginal base, SonucTabani=result-converted base}
function SayiCevir(Sayi:String;const SayiTabani,SonucTabani:Word):String;
 function ChToRkm(const C:Char):Byte;
 var B:Byte absolute C;{c ile b aynı adresteki değişkenlerdir. c:='B' olursa b değeri 66 olur veya b:=65 olursa c değeri 'A' olur}
 begin
   if C>='A' then Result:=B-55 else Result:=B-48;
 end;
 function RkmToCh(B:Byte):Char;
 var C:Char absolute B;
 begin
   if B>9 then B:=B+55 else B:=B+48;
   Result:=C;
 end;
const AltSinir=1; UstSinir=35;
var i,j:Integer; fSayi,Basamak:Int64;
begin
  //if (SayiTabani=SonucTabani) then Result:=Sayi else
  if (SayiTabani<=AltSinir) or (SonucTabani<AltSinir) or (SayiTabani>UstSinir) or (SonucTabani>UstSinir) then
   raise Exception.CreateFmt('%d tabanındaki sayı %d tabanına çevrilmek isteniyor fakat desteklenen taban aralığı %d-%d''dir.',[SayiTabani,SonucTabani,AltSinir,UstSinir])
  else begin
    Sayi:=UpperCase(Trim(Sayi));
    fSayi:=0;Basamak:=1;
    for i:=Length(Sayi) downto 1 do begin
      j:=ChToRkm(Sayi[i]);
      if j>=SayiTabani then raise Exception.CreateFmt('%s sayısı %d tabanlı bir sayı değildir.',[Sayi,SayiTabani]);
      fSayi:=fSayi+(j*Basamak);
      Basamak:=Basamak*SayiTabani;
    end;
    Result:='';
    if fSayi=0 then Result:='0'
    else while fSayi>0 do begin
      Result:=RkmToCh(fSayi mod SonucTabani)+Result;
      fSayi:=fSayi div SonucTabani;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Im using this codes for converting base of number to other base. This codes is working normally but there is a limitation of length of number. For example,

```
I convert:

String:=SayiCevir('123456789',10,11); //Thats OK.

If I wrote:

String:=SayiCevir('12345678912345678998765432101234569870',10,11); //FAIL!!
```

Second codes arent working, dont return any result. So;
How can I convert base of "LONG" string of integer to other base? I think problem is Length of String? Right?

Comment: Why do you insist on trying to convert these huge string "numbers" (that aren't actual numbers) into numeric types that don't exist? If you explained what you're actually trying to accomplish, I'm sure someone here could suggest a realistic alternate approach that avoids all of these silly conversion efforts you're trying over and over.

Comment: Indeed, I've never ever even thought of any possible case when I might need to use a number like 12345678912345678998765432101234569870

Comment: @JerryDodge Crypto, prime factorisation etc.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is maximum integer size in Delphi.

MaxInt = 2147483647

MaxInt64 = 9223372036854775807

You number = 12345678912345678998765432101234569870

So definetly it is beyond what Delphi can do.

You may need to use BigInt.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/bigint-dl/

Comment: I used it but I got accsess violation error.

Comment: how about this http://delphiforfun.org/programs/Library/BigFloat.htm

Comment: or this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bigint/files/?source=navbar

Comment: No I didnt. How can I convert Long Decimal to Hex?

Comment: "I used it but I got accsess violation error." doesn't tell us anything. Surely there's something wrong with how it's being used, and considering the popularity of such a library, I doubt the library has a bug keeping this from being possible.