# Delphi base convert Binary to Decimal

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Im converting binary to decimal and Im converting Decimal to binary. My problem is Length of the binary integer. For example:

```
Convertx("001110",2,10) = 14

Convertx("14",10,2) = 1110
```

But length of the binary is NOT constant, So How can I get exact original binary with zeros front of it? How can I get "001110" instead of "1110" ?

I m using this function in Delphi 7. -> [How can I convert base of decimal string to another base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598629/how-can-i-convert-base-of-decimal-string-to-another-base)

Comment: `001110` and `1110` are identical values. How is the function supposed to know that you need left-zero padding if you don't tell it? If you need left-zero padding, modify your function to accept a length parameter, and add the zeros you need until your result is the proper length.

Comment: How about at least making an effort to do it yourself, instead of expecting someone here to do it for you? I've told you what you need to do; you could at least **try** to figure it out yourself.

Comment: I just used function which in link. Did you check the link ?

Comment: Why do I need to check the link? Change the function to suit your needs, using the information I've already given you. Learn to do things yourself instead of depending on others to do it for you.

Comment: I understand. Im working in my mind. how can I tell you all things?

Answer (score 2):

The function you are using returns a string that is the shortest length required to express the value you have converted.

Any zeroes in front of that string are simply padding - they do not alter the binary value represented.  If you need a string of a minimum length then you need to add this "padding" yourself.  e.g. if you want a binary representation of a "byte" (i.e. 8 binary digits) then the minimum length you would need is 8:

```
binStr := Convertx("14",10,2);
while Length(binStr) < 8 do
  binStr := '0' + binStr;
```

If you need the exact number of zeroes that were included in the "padding" of some original binary value when converting from binary to decimal and then back to "original" binary again, then this is impossible unless you *separately* record how many padding zeroes there were or the length of the original string, including those zeroes.

i.e. in your example, the ConvertX function has no idea (and now way to figure out) that the number "14" it is asked to convert to binary was originally converted from a 6 digit binary string with 2 leading zeroes, rather than an 8 digit binary with 4 leading zeroes (or a 16 digit binary with 12 leading zeroes, etc etc).

Answer (score 1):

What you are hoping for is impossible. Consider

```
Convertx('001110', 2, 10)
```

and

```
Convertx('1110', 2, 10)
```

These both return the same output, 14. At that point there is no way to recover the length of the original input.

The way forward is therefore clear. You must remember the length of the original binary, as well as the equivalent decimal. However, once you have reached that conclusion then you might wonder whether there is an even simpler approach. Just remember the original binary value and save yourself having to convert back from decimal.